# Packaging Visual Basic .net program and resources together to make it stand-alone exe

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, executable, vb.net-2010

I'm developing a very simple program in VB2010 Express that will create folders based on entries in a remote database. I am fully aware that the minimum requirement to run the exe is the latest .net framework, however I have a few added resources to the file, and when I try to run the executable on another computer, it fails to run stating that the resources are missing.

How do i compile my VB code AND the resources together into a stand-alone executable that only requires the .net framework to be installed?

I have already tried to google this issue, however every answer I find has nothing to do with my initial question...

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to describe "added resources" better.

Comment: @Hans - Primarily images for the splash screen, and icons for the program.

Comment: That doesn't help much.  Use Project + Properties, Resources tab to add resources that are baked inside the EXE file.  They can't get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you mark your `resx` files (or other resource files such as images etc) as `Embedded Resource` in their `Build Action`.